# Video player give Error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: ipad

i am creating one iPad application in that i want to open media player to play video. For this i create one button in ViewDidLoad() method. Bellow is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]] autorelease];

    m_btn2000 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] autorelease];
    m_btn2000.frame = CGRectMake(180, 330, 130, 200);
   [m_btn2000 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    m_btn2000.clipsToBounds = YES;
   [m_btn2000 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:m_btn2000];
}
```

Bellow is my button clicked method code:

```
- (void)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSString *filePath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test_video" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath1];
    m_moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    m_moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
   [m_moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1026, 748)];
   [self.view addSubview:m_moviePlayer.view];
   [m_moviePlayer play];
}
```

when i m going to click on button it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.
But i notice one thing that when i put above whole code which in button clicked method putting in ViewDidLoad() method it play a video in player proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is : you are creating a button with + (factory method) and you are sending `autorelease` message.

you need to change this line from:
`m_btn2000 = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] autorelease];`

to

```
  m_btn2000 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Comment: best one...solved.  Can u please give some brief elaboration on this ??

Comment: +1, it (the button object) is already `autorelease`d by the factory method.